# Integrating Google Cloud Speech API with Angular 7 directly

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7, google-speech-api

I have been going around trying to integrate Google Speech API with angular directly to use voice recognition over multiple browser and over the mobile web browser. My question is:  Is there a way to connect angular with the google api through grpc to live stream the recognition?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Obvi](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/obvi/) to learn how to build a client side Cloud Speech API client over WebRTC. [Obvi](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/obvi) is a Polymer 3+ webcomponent/button for doing speech recognition.

Comment: It seems Obvi doesn't support to sending a audio stream to Google Speech API, it just sends the audio content.